# Android - How to Integrate Tumblr Login

Tags: android, tumblr

I integrated Tumblr in my Android application. I want to get login user profile in my app like Facebook. is it possible?

My Code for successful login is:

```
public void onLoginSuccessful(LoginResult loginResult) {
    if(loginResult != null && !TextUtils.isEmpty(loginResult.getOAuthToken()) && !TextUtils.isEmpty(loginResult.getOAuthTokenSecret())) {
        Log.i(TAG, "Tumblr Token : " + loginResult.getOAuthToken());
        Log.i(TAG, "Tumblr Secret Token : " + loginResult.getOAuthTokenSecret());
        Button btnClickMe = (Button) findViewById(R.id.mainactivity_button);
        btnClickMe.setText("Congratulations, Tumblr login succeeded");
        btnClickMe.setEnabled(false);
    }
}
```

Comment: Refer [this](https://github.com/FredrikL/android-ttTumblr) and [this](https://www.tumblr.com/docs/en/api/v2) . It will help you

Comment: I want to get user data from Tumblr SDK not From EditText.